# unfocus browser flash player to use shortcuts

Tags: flash, shortcuts

Once I click to play a video in youtube I can no longer use any other shortcut (eg: <kbd>ALT+PGDWN</kbd> to change tab), I need to click somewhere else in the page, is this normal? how can I un-focus the flash player via keyboard?

Thanks

**Edit**

I'm using Firefox (the latest) in Ubuntu 12.10 on a toshiba laptop m200

Comment: You need to give more information, such as your browser, your desktop environment, etc.

Comment: thanks, updated, please let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

These days I can achieve the result by using the full screen shortcut (`f`).  If you're already on full-screen you need to press it twice, but invariably once you're back in full screen the cursor arrows work as expected.